# Partclone broken image restore

Tags: disk-image, clonezilla

I have a partclone image of my hard drive which is obviously broken. I thougt I could rely on this backup but unfortunately I cant. It is my last chance to achieve the desired data so I would spend some effort...

At first I tried [this tutorial](http://blog.christosoft.de/2012/05/mount-clonezilla-image-to-restore-single-file-browse/) to open my image which creates an img-for me but I cannot mount this file. Later I used this command `sudo partclone.ext4 -r -W -C -L partclone.log -s sda10.ext4-ptcl-img -o sda10.img` from [this page](https://simonstamm.de/clonezilla-image-mounten-um-einzelne-dateien-wiederherzustellen/) which fails, also with parameters like `force` and `ignore_crc`.

Then I booted the CloneZilla live CD and tried a restore of my image. As expected, it said that my image is broken.

Probably some data is still undamaged. What chances do I have to fix my unmountable image file? Which utilities do you recommend?

Comment: As I am not allowed to post images, I do it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTI1q.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHCBg.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jciS.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaxS4.jpg

Comment: Mounting my img file brings the error EXT4-fs (loop0): bad geometry: block count 120421632 exceeds size of device (120067606 blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the problem was, but [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/cannot-mount-hard-disk-block-count-exceeds-size-of-device-bad-partition-table-880149/#post4427361) solved my problem. All my data is accessible again! I hope this is helpful for further people!